# Let users hide posts on wordpress website

Tags: wordpress, calendar, hide

I'm building a Wordpress website with events. People can register to this website and view the events I have placed inside a calendar. People can RSVP to an event OR they can hide an event.

What I want: Every user needs the possibility to hide an event but only for him or herself. Not for every user.

My problem: Whenever I try to hide a post, it's hidden for every user. Not just for that one user that wants to hide it.

How can I achieve this? I spent hours looking online but couldn't find a solution. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by automatically registrering categories for every user. So they always see their version of the calendar. Changes an individual user makes will not affect the calendar of other users.